# How are rainbow-liquidy artworks like these modelled?

Tags: modeling

(I dont use Blender very regularly and am currently quite rusty)

I've been seeing art like this a lot lately (maybe some algorithm has discovered I like such things) and have been wondering how people do this. I understand that the material in such artworks are going to be tricky: refractive-glass, i think? But I was just wondering how are such sculptures modelled? Is this a flat plane with some bumps? Is it a completely different shape clicked up-close that we cant see?

For the below photos, the artist listed Cinema 4D, Octane and Photoshop but I'm sure Blender can achieve this too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think for a lot of these images the modeling could just as well be some procedural displacement on a relatively simple object, most of the work is in the shader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly the same, but I just took a cube and subdivided it a couple of times, then used Mesh->Transform->Randomize and moved some vertices around. I added a Subdivision modifier to smooth it out and then applied a Glass shader. Then I chose "Environment Texture" for the background and downloaded a random swirly color image from a Google search:

[image]

Then zoom in so you can't see the shape/background.

You could also do crazier things with the shader but really the refraction of the glass can do the work for you.

Here's one using a different background, and just Suzanne - so zero modeling work at all!

[image]